# Subclass controller with subclass model

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working on an ASP.Net MVC 3 project where a lot of really simple entities just need basic CRUD support from the Administrative interface. All of these entities have a simple domain object with Id, Name and there is an abstract base class `NamedEntity` for that purpose.

I have a basic controller, `NamedEntityController<T> where T : NamedEntity` that can handle simple crud operations, with all of its methods virtual. There's a nice little `NamedEntityCreateOrUpdateModel<T>` which is used to pass data back & forth to the views.

Now I have a particular subclass of `NamedEntity` called `Topic` that has additional properties and in particular, has a Parent/Child relationship with other Topics, so we need to capture the integer Id of the Parent which would have no meaning for other `NamedEntity` operations. To do that, I subclassed to `TopicsController: NamedEntityController<Topic>` and `TopicCreateOrUpdateModel : NamedEntityCreateOrUpdateModel<Topic>`

(Before anyone bites my head off, all the real work is done in a Tasks layer, I'm just simplifying the problem description here.)

The base controller defines

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Edit(NamedEntityCreateOrEditModel<T> Model)
    { ... }
```

The subclass defines

```
[HttpPost]
public override ActionResult Edit(NamedEntityCreateOrEditModel<Topic> Model)
{
TopicCreateOrEditModel tm = Model as TopicCreateOrEditModel;
...
}
```

(Not shown for brevity: The "Get" version of Edit for each correctly sets up either the basic `NamedEntityCreateOrEditModel` or the Topic-specific subclass of such and returns a `View()` on that Model.)

I can clearly see from debugging breakpoints, that the subclass's Edit (post) method is being called. But the cast shown above always result in `null`, thus defeating the point of the subclass.

If I try to create

```
[HttpPost]
public override ActionResult Edit(TopicCreateOrEditModel Model) { ... }
```

MVC complains that the action is ambiguous between that new method and the base class method.

Is there an easy solution to this problem? I could bypass the base class controller / model completely in this case, and basically say 'if you need additional fields beyond the simple ones, don't inherit' but that seems very wrong, especially since the domain objects ARE inheriting.

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly using `TryUpdateModel` in the Action, you can remove the parameter and make the signature the same. This allows the use of the `override` keyword, like so:

```
public class A { }
public class B : A { }

public class AController {

    [HttpPost]
    public virtual ActionResult Edit() {
        A a = new A();
        TryUpdateModel<A>(a);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
            a.save();
    }
}

public class BController : AController {

    [HttpPost]
    public override ActionResult Edit() {
        B b = new B();
        TryUpdateModel<B>(b);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
            b.save();
    }
}
```

This fixed the AmbiguousMethodException for me, and calls to both `Edit` actions routed correctly. There may, however, be security concerns that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

When your subclass' Edit is called, is it being passed `NamedEntityCreateOrEditModel<Topic>` or `TopicCreateOrEditModel`? The former would fail the cast (needless to say, you can cast a derived class to its base but not vice versa).

Comment: It has to be passed the former, because otherwise it can't override. I've cast base classes to their subclasses before, when I know that the object is in fact the subclass, but in the case, it's just not happening.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently MVC passes an instance of `NamedEntityCreateOrEditModel<Topic>` instead of `TopicCreateOrEditModel`.  Since I can't see the value of polymorphism for `Edit` in this case, I suppose explicitly mark it as `new` should do fine (yes, it's a hack).

```
[HttpPost]
public new ActionResult Edit(TopicCreateOrEditModel Model) { ... }
```

A more orthodox approach probably is writing a custom model binder for `NamedEntityCreateOrEditModel<Topic>` type to build an instance of `TopicCreateOrEditModel` if the current controller is `TopicsController`.

Or, knowing nothing about your current use of inheritance, simply remove the `Edit` (and similar CRUD methods) in `NamedEntityController<T>` as I can't see its value.  If you're having good reason for its existence, ignore this suggestion.

Comment: Technically it's not `new` if the parameters change (compile-time warning). Whether this would actually work is another question... my guess is that the result would still be ambigiuous between whether I wanted the base class or the subclass edit method.

Comment: As suspected, this still creates an ambigious call between the base class and the subclass. 

I know nothing about custom model binders yet (first MVC project), so I'll go Google that and see what I can find. 

I expect some subclasses to really only need to update Name (the only property besides Id in the base class), because that is their only property, which is why I thought I would include that in the base class, but you may be right that in this scenario, it doesn't help enough.